Zoho Deluge - Creating a new note for a new lead (Zoho CRM)
I created a function that the email handler uses. Works fine without the note part. Problem is that I can't get the ParentID because it is a new lead. What am I missing?
newNote = map();
newNote.put("Parent_Id", input); // This is the issue
newNote.put("$se_module","Leads");
newNote.put("Note_Title","Note title");
newNote.put("Note_Content","Note content");

resp = zoho.crm.createRecord("Notes",newNote);

leadinfo = {"First_Name":eFirstName,"Last_Name":eLastName,"Company":eCompany,"Email":eEmail,"Description":eMessage,"User_type":eUserType};

response = zoho.crm.createRecord("Leads",leadinfo);
return [response, resp];


leadinfo = {"First_Name":eFirstName,"Last_Name":eLastName,"Company":eCompany,"Email":eEmail,"Description":eMessage,"User_type":eUserType};

response = zoho.crm.createRecord("Leads",leadinfo);
newNote = map();
newNote.put("Parent_Id", response.get("id")); // First Created a new Lead then Create a Note Against that same Lead by passing the leadId.
newNote.put("$se_module","Leads");
newNote.put("Note_Title","Note title");
newNote.put("Note_Content","Note content");

resp = zoho.crm.createRecord("Notes",newNote);

return [response, resp];


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
